# Dynamic YAMLs for Docker Compose

Tags: docker-compose

Currently I find myself managing a set of embarassingly similar YAMLs for environment profiles. I see there a scaling trouble if there will be *lots* of dynamic environments (i.e. fluid acceptance test configurations, with disposable environments you can do that!)

Has anybody done a working implementation to build YAMLs dynamically on scale based on some generic represenation ( kind of CasC level 2 beyond some naive scripting), or if this makes no sense, why and which way is to prefer then.

Comment: Do you already use [variable substitution](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#variable-substitution) in your compose files? If they really are "embarassingly similar", that might be an option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One could use the same docker-compose file for dev, test, acceptance and production (DTAP) systems. Things that deviate per environment, e.g. passwords could be defined in an .env file.

If .env files are not a solution for some reason then one could create different docker-compose files, e.g. docker-compose.override (dev), docker-compose.test, docker-compose.acc and docker-compose.prd.

I personally prefer the first option, e.g. using .env files and a docker-compose.override for dev.

Comment: Although this answer already has some years on its shoulds, coming by it just now and seeing that it's the accepted answer I just want to add: Before you consider running docker-compose in production, think about running even a 1-node swarm so you have access to the "deploy" key in your docker-compose file. Compose itself was really not meant to run a prod environment.

Answer (score 1):

[SaltStack](https://saltstack.com/) is great at generating these kinds of files based on metadata you feed to it via "pillars" as Salt itself uses YAML files heavily. Salt uses a [Jinja templating engine](http://jinja.pocoo.org/) (though others are also available).

Similarly, [Puppet](https://puppet.com/) also uses YAML heavily and is able to do the same using an [ERB](https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/5.3/lang_template_erb.html) template.

If you find that some of this metadata are things like a listening IP address or a hostname, these systems automatically generate variables such as this using [facter](https://docs.puppet.com/facter/) facts or salt [grains](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/grains/) respectively which can further reduce the amount of metadata you need to suply.

[Chef](https://www.chef.io/chef/) is probably also capable of this, though I am not familiar with that configuration management system.